# Call parent magic method from override magic method in a trait

Tags: php, traits

### Problem

I am open sourcing a trait which includes the magic method `__call()`. During testing, I encountered a challenge when the parent class of the class using the trait contains the `__call` method.

### What I Tried

```
trait SomeTrait {
    public function __call($method, array $parameters) {
        // ...
        return parent::__call($method, $parameters);
    }
}
```

This results in the fatal error: **Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent**

I also tried the following, based on some other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151722/php-overriding-parent-methods-with-call):

```
return call_user_func_array([$this, '__call'], [$method, $parameters]);
```

This results in a **Segmentation fault: 11**. I imagine because of an infinite call loop.

### Question

How can I invoke the parent's `__call` method from within the `__call` method of the trait?

If it is not possible from within the trait directly, how might I invoke the parent's `__call` method otherwise?

Comment: Wait... should not the classes __call override the traits __call?

Comment: Not if it's inherited - see Example #2 in the [Precedence section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Precedence is local, trait, parent. So in my case the trait takes precedence, but I want to call the inherited method.

Comment: [`E_CANNOT_REPRODUCE`](http://3v4l.org/ZKStr)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check code below:

```
trait SomeTrait
{
    public function __call($method, array $parameters)
    {
        // ...
        return is_callable(['parent', '__call']) ? parent::__call($method, $parameters) : null;
    }
}

class GreatParentClass
{
    public function __call($method, array $parameters)
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

class ParenClassWithoutCall
{

}

class ProxyClass extends GreatParentClass
{

}

class FooClass extends ProxyClass
{
    use SomeTrait;
}

class BarClass extends GreatParentClass
{
    use SomeTrait;
}

class BazClass extends ParenClassWithoutCall
{
    use SomeTrait;
}

class SomeClassWithoutParent
{
    use SomeTrait;
}

$class = new FooClass();
var_dump($class->foobar());

$class = new BarClass();
var_dump($class->foobar());

$class = new BazClass();
var_dump($class->foobar());

$class = new SomeClassWithoutParent();
var_dump($class->foobar());
```

This will print:

```
string(3) "bar"
string(3) "bar"
NULL
NULL
```

Sandbox with the code to check:
http://3v4l.org/R8hI3

**EDIT: I think this will cover all possibilities.**

Comment: + Would have never guessed testing for the `__call()` method directly by passing the string 'parent'. Feels like a hack, but works. Thanks.

Comment: Np. Check is_callable documentation - it looks weird but in fact it's proper approach. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem here is that if you use this trait in a class without a parent, this call will fail.  You might consider checking if the class has a parent before making the call to the parent function. That might look like this:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    public function __call($method, array $parameters) {
        // ...
        if (count(class_parents($this)) {
            return parent::__call($method, $parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

I would also say that this may not be the best design approach.  I don't think something like a trait, which is supposed to present a portable, composable set of functionality, should be changing/overriding functionality in the adopting class' inheritance chain.

Comment: After testing, this solution is incomplete. Just because a class has a parent doesn't mean it has the `__call()` method.